# Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on separate SSDs

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

First off I have Windows 10 on its own SSD (/dev/sda). I would like to install Ubuntu on its own SSD (/dev/sdb). As I was going through installation I didn't get an option to [install Ubuntu alongside Windows](https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2015/07/install-ubuntu-alongside-windows-100599650-large.png), so I chose "other".

From there I created a swap and created a ext4 on sdb. Now I need to choose where to install the boot loader. Do I chose /dev/sda? or is it /dev/sdb?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install. It  should be same boot mode as Windows. If UEFI, it does not matter what you say, it will install grub2's .efi boot files into /EFI/Ubuntu folder in the ESP on the Windows drive. I prefer to also have an ESP on sdb, but it is not used by default. If BIOS select sdb's MBR.  Most Windows installs are UEFI, since Microsoft has required pre-installed Windows to be UEFI on gpt partitioned drives since 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Either is valid, just so you remember where you put it.

Since most folks are more likely to assume /dev/sda, that's where I put it. That's not the same as /dev/sda**1** and I strongly recommend not using /dev/sda**1** .

BTW, if you are installing 18.04 or later AND do not intend to [hibernate](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) Ubuntu, you do not need a swap partition; [Ubiquity](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ubiquity.8.html) (the installer app) will make a swap file for you. You can back up and remove the swap partition if you wish.

The other use case for a swap partition is obsolete; the Linux kernel before late 2017 had performance issues with swap files, which are now fixed.

Comment: Can you explain why you `strongly recommend not using /dev/sda1` ?